# Which layer in RMI performs marshalling and unmarshalling?

Tags: java, rmi

My question is all theoretical. Actually, in RMI among Stub and Skeleton layer which layer performs Marshalling and unmarshalling. DO both layers performs both function or what???

Answer (score 1):

Both layers perform both functions.  It is explained in the [RMI architecture documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch2.html).

- The stub marshals the request, and unmarshals the reply.
- The skeleton unmarshals the request and marshals the reply.